# Is it possible to perfect forward from a container to a value type?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to build a polymorphic container and I would like the container to cast implicitly to its underlying type if the container is valid. I got the implicit conversion part right, but it's always copying and I don't know why. Here is relevant part of the implementation:

```cpp
struct polymorphic
{
    // [...] Implementation details

    polymorphic(polymorphic&&) noexcept;
    polymorphic(const polymorphic&) noexcept;

    polymorphic& operator=(polymorphic&&) noexcept;
    polymorphic& operator=(const polymorphic&) noexcept;

    template <typename T>
    polymorphic(T&&) noexcept;

    template <typename T>
    polymorphic& operator=(T&&) noexcept;

    template <typename T>
    T Move() &&;

    template <typename T>
    T& Get();

    template <typename T>
    const T& Get() const;

    template <typename T>
    operator T() &&
    {
        return Move<T>(); // Moves the underlying type out of the container
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator T&() &
    {
        return Get<T>(); // Return the underlying type by ref
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator const T&() const &
    {
        return Get<T>(); // Return the underlying type by const ref
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    polymorphic poly = "answer to the universe";
    std::string s1 = poly;            // operator const T&() const &
    std::string s2 = std::move(poly); // operator const T&() const & but should be operator T() &&
}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: [Your problem is not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/d9Tqv1). As you can see there, it correctly calls the move version.

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: How do you know "I got the implicit conversion part right, but it's always copying and I don't know why."?

Comment: @Skewjo The thing is in production. I can't show the whole example, but it's written for unreal engine. For my use case, I was accessing the value by const ref, so never copying or moving. I'm just trying to figure out why I can't get the implicit move semantics right.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot it seems to be an issue with MSVC https://godbolt.org/z/E47sef

Comment: Conversion to template reference is an unclear part of the standard. I would report a bug to them to see what they think, they usually respond quite quickly

Comment: @sturcotte06, glad you found your issue. Hope my first question didn't sound too combative. It may help you to include ```msvc``` as a tag for future issues.